# sklearn , change default parameters in cross_val_score

Tags: python, function, parameters, scikit-learn, evaluation

I am evaluating text classification predictions , with **cross_val_score.**
I need to evaluate my predictions with *recall_score function* , but with parameter **average = 'macro'**. cross_val_score sets it to the default parameter , *binary* , which doesnt work to my code. Is there any way to call recall_score with a different parameter , or change the default parameter to macro.

```
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv= kfold, scoring= 'recall')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use "recall_macro" in it like this:

```
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv= kfold, scoring= 'recall_macro')
```

According to the [documentation of metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter)

```
‘f1’                metrics.f1_score            for binary targets
‘f1_micro’          metrics.f1_score            micro-averaged
‘f1_macro’          metrics.f1_score            macro-averaged
‘f1_weighted’       metrics.f1_score            weighted average
‘f1_samples’        metrics.f1_score            by multilabel sample
‘neg_log_loss’      metrics.log_loss            requires predict_proba support
‘precision’ etc.    metrics.precision_score     suffixes apply as with ‘f1’
‘recall’ etc.       metrics.recall_score        suffixes apply as with ‘f1’
```

As you can see, its specified that all suffixes apply to "recall".

Alternatively, you can also use [`make_scorer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer) like this:

```
# average can take values from 'macro', 'micro', 'weighted' etc as specified above
scorer = make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label=None, average='macro')
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(estimator, X, Y, cv= kfold,
                                          scoring= scorer)
```